# Heroku Error during websocket handshake 503

Tags: heroku, websocket

I'm trying to connect to websockets in heroku but it's saying Error during websocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503. The error in Dev Tools is 'Service unavailable'.

Server code

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: app,  port:5001});
```

Client code(I am replacing the port to 5001 as well)

```
  var host = location.origin
          .replace(/^http/, 'ws')
          .replace('5000','5001');


var ws = new WebSocket(host);
```

I've did the same in development and I managed to connect. Any help to troubleshoot? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this was a stupid mistake from my side. What I did was follow the example on [here](https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-ws-test) and everything was ok..

Basically, I omitted this part from my code:

```
// app.listen(config.port, function(){
    // console.log("App started on port " + config.port);
});
```

and included this instead

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(config.port);
```